# Wordpress panel cannot be opened after setting the url incorrectly

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress panel cannot be opened after typos set WordPress Address and site address in "general" settings. How to deal with it?

`Settings --> general --> WordPress Address (URL)` 
and 
`Settings --> general --> Site Address (URL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry, you can overcome it

- Open CPANEL from your hosting,
- open "PHPMyAdmin"
- Search for your WordPress database
- Look for the table with the `_options` suffix
- Then edit the `siteurl` and `home` columns, please fill

  `option_value` with the correct address of your site